# Akka not loading application.conf

Tags: scala, akka

I'm pretty new to Akka and I'm having trouble getting the `application.conf` file to load. I've defined a relatively simple conf file, consisting of:

```
akka {
  logLevel = "NONE"
  stdout-logLevel = "NONE"
}
```

From what I understand, this should be picked up automatically (having put it in the `src/main/resources` directory). However, when I load the default logger and output "INFO" (*doing greet*) messages, I am still seeing them in the console (see following code).

```
import akka.actor.{ActorRef, Actor, Props}
import akka.event.Logging

object HelloWorldActor {
  case object Tick
}


class HelloWorldActor extends Actor {
  val logger = Logging(context.system, this)
  var greeter : Option[ActorRef] = None

  override def preStart() = {
    greeter = Some(context.actorOf(Props[Greeter], "greeter"))
  }

  def doGreet(): Unit = {
    logger.info("doing greet")
    greeter match {
      case Some(g) => g ! Greeter.Greet
    }
  }
  def receive: Actor.Receive = {
    case HelloWorldActor.Tick => this.doGreet()
  }
}
```

The only thing I can think of is that I have defined a kernel to run it in stand-alone mode and I'm not sure if there is something extra that I should be doing there to load the configuration.

I've put my project up on GitHub for better inspection of what I am doing:https://github.com/JohnMurray/hello-akka

Any help is greatly appreciated since I'm currently an Akka newbie. Also, I should mention that I have read through the config documentation online, but it didn't help me in this particular case.

thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try putting your file into src/main/resources/ - application.conf is not a scala file, so it doesn't belong in src/main/scala/resources which is the folder for the package *root*.resources scala sources.

OK. I see what is the problem now. I don't think there's a loglevel setting NONE.

According to the [doc](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/scala/logging.html) there are four settings:

```
# Options: ERROR, WARNING, INFO, DEBUG
loglevel = "DEBUG"
```

Try setting it to WARNING.

Also, you have typo in loglevel - please note it's not a camelCase name, but all-lower loglevel.

Side note - add akka microkernel plugin to your SBT build and add runner that can be launched either with run or re-start action.

Comment: Sorry, that was actually a typo. I have my application.conf within the `src/main/resources` folder. The GitHub project should reflect that as well. My bad.

Comment: Tested with setup like yours and validated that NONE gives out error message, and WARNING/ERROR works just fine, so most likely it is typo. Also please note that you may have other .conf file that overrides real akka.loglevel property.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. I'm not quite sure where I got `NONE` from, but thank you so much for the help!